# shiny ggplot with interactive y does not plot correctly

Tags: r, ggplot2, shiny, interactive

I am trying to create an interface where the user selects the y variables from a drop down menu and then can observe the bar chart with the observations selected. 
However, the output is not right as the app is not able to read my Y variables. Whenever I changed the Y variable from the drop down menu, the chart doesn't change at all.

Attached are screenshots of my csv data sheet, as well as the incorrect output chart I got from running the codes below:

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NICxY.jpg)

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DHAqI.jpg)

```
shinyUI(fluidPage(
titlePanel("Volvo Sales Analysis"),

fluidRow(

  column(4,selectInput("Year",
              label = "Choose a year",
              choices = as.list(c("Y2004","Y2005","Y2006","Y2007","Y2008","Y2009","Y2010","Y2011","Y2012",
                          "Y2013", "Y2014", "Y2015")),selected = "Y2015")),

  column(12,plotOutput("brandplot"))

  )
))


shinyServer(
function(input, output) {

brand_sales<-read.csv("C:/Shiny R/Sales by brand.csv", header=TRUE,check.names=FALSE)

output$brandplot= renderPlot({

ggplot(brand_sales,aes(x=brand_sales$Brands,y=input$Year,fill=Brands))+xlab("Brands")+ylab("Sales Volume")+geom_bar(stat="identity")

})

})
```

In the "as.list(c("Y2004","Y2005"....)" function I did not use "colnames(brand_sales)" because if I do, the column name "Brand" will also be shown in the drop down menu and I don't want that. I only want users to select a year between Y2004 and Y2015.

**I have also tried "aes_string()" when referencing the columns in ggplot. But the output page generates the error "object 'Brands' not found".**

Comment: You should not be using `aes()` when you want to specify a column. Try searching for `aes_string()` Maybe [this example](https://gist.github.com/jcheng5/3239667) will help.

Comment: I tried aes_string() but the output page generates the error "object 'Brands' not found'.

Comment: Put `Brands` in quotes in `aes_string` (all variables should be in quotes).

Comment: @aosmith: I also tried "aes_string(x="Brands", y=input$Year, fill=Brands)". The error still exists :(

Comment: Put `fill = "Brands"` instead of `fill = Brands`.  Look at the help page for `aes_string`, there is an example there.

Comment: @aosmith: Thank you so much! That corrects the problem. I never thought could put quotes around column names since I usually use "dataset$columnname" or "dataset[n]". But I learned something new today. :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to **aosmith**'s answer, I was able to fix the problem and got the chart to display correctly. It turns out that the correct codes to ggplot should be:

"ggplot(brand_sales,aes_string(x="Brands",y=input$Year,fill="Brands"))+xlab("Brands")+ylab("Sales     Volume")+geom_bar(stat="identity")"

The key is to surround the X and Fill variables with quotes as this is the right way to name columns in aes_string.

Thanks again **aosmith** and **MrFlink** for your inputs!